# First Homology group of the Klein Bottle using Hurewicz, problem with the abelianization of $\pi_1(K)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying algebraic topology and want to compute $H_1(K)$ using Hurewicz. Now I already know that we have a representation of $K$ given by
\begin{equation*}
K=\langle a,b\,|\,aba^{-1}b=1\rangle
\end{equation*}
and that
\begin{equation*}
\pi_1(K)=\langle a,b\rangle/\langle abab^{-1}\rangle.
\end{equation*}
According to Hurewicz, I have to calculate the abelianization of $\pi_1(K)$ and that's where I have problems; I know that I need to find
\begin{equation*}
\pi_1(K)/[\pi_1(K),\pi_1(K)]
\end{equation*}where the commutator subgroup is generated by $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ for $x,y\in\pi_1(K)$ but I cannot find a way to write a general element of $\pi_1(K)$ and even less how to calculate the commutator. Could someone help me to see how we would get $[\pi_1(K),\pi_1(K)]=\langle\beta^2\rangle$ as I saw in Hatcher?

Comment: You don't need to calculate the commutator subgroup. The abelianization is the *abelian* group with the same presentation as the original group. So it's generated by two commuting elements $a, b$ subject to the relation $aba^{-1} b = 1$. Commuting the $b$ and the $a^{-1}$ gives that this relation, in the abelianization, is equivalent to $b^2 = 1$. So...?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I mean, now it follows more or less directly because we have $\pi_1(K)^{\text{ab}}=\langle a,b|b^2=1\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is exactly what we wanted to obtain :)

Comment: Yes, that's right!